# Events are not triggered by my javascript SignalR Azure connection

Tags: javascript, azure, signalr, owin, .net-4.8

I have set up a SignalR connection between an Azure server and client. The connection is created but events are not being triggered on the client.

I can send a message from the client to the server and I've confirmed that the server receives this. However, events on the client are not being triggered. I even try to invoke an event on the client from the client ('sendMessage' you can see in my client code below) but this does not trigger.

I have read that at least one event needs to be attached to the hub proxy before the connection.start is called; so have done this - but the events still aren't working.

My client side code is:

```
"use strict";

//Disable send button until connection is established
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

var connection = $.hubConnection();
connection.url = 'https://localhost:44444/signalr/hubs';
var reportHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy("reportHub");

reportHubProxy.on("receiveMessage", function (user, message)
{
    console.log(user + ' ' + message + ' receiveMessage - connection ID=' + connection.id);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    // We can assign user-supplied strings to an element's textContent because it
    // is not interpreted as markup. If you're assigning in any other way, you 
    // should be aware of possible script injection concerns.
    li.textContent = "${user} says ${message}";
});

reportHubProxy.on("sendMessage", function (user, message)
{
    console.log(user + ' ' + message);
});

connection.start()
    .done(function ()
    {
        document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
        console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id);
        document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event)
        {
            var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
            var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
            console.log(user + ' ' + message + ' sent - connection ID=' + connection.id);
            reportHubProxy.invoke("sendMessage", user, message)
                .then(function (err)
                {
                    return console.log(user + ' ' + message + ' complete - connection ID=' + connection.id);
                })
                .catch(function (err)
                {
                    return console.error(err.toString());
                });
            //event.preventDefault();
        });
    })
    .fail(function ()
    {
        console.log('Could not Connect!');
    });
```

I'm seeing the console logs from connection.start but not those from receiveMessage or sendMessage.

My server-side code is simple and seems to work fine:

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class ReportHub
    Inherits Hub

    Public Async Function SendMessage(ByVal user As String, ByVal message As String) As Task
        Await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message)
    End Function
End Class
```

```
Imports Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

Public Class Startup

    Public Sub Configuration(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
        app.MapSignalR()
    End Sub

End Class
```

I have installed Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.js on the client which has installed the file jquery.signalR-2.4.2.js.

Comment: I built a full blown example using angular here. Pls check out https://github.com/ayyappangs/AzureSignalR.Angular

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian - thanks for that. That's a useful link, but I need to integrate this into an existing project which doesn't use Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now got this working by doing two things:

1. Wrapping the code in

```
$(function (){ }):
```

2. Switching to using a generated proxy as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

I tried doing 1. first, but that didn't work on its own.

So my client code now looks like this:

```
$(function ()
{
    "use strict";

    //Disable send button until connection is established
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

    $.connection.hub.url = 'https://localhost:44444/signalr/hubs';
    var reportHubProxy = $.connection.reportHub;
    reportHubProxy.client.receiveMessage = function (user, message)
    {
        console.log(user + ' ' + message + ' received - connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id);
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
        // We can assign user-supplied strings to an element's textContent because it
        // is not interpreted as markup. If you're assigning in any other way, you 
        // should be aware of possible script injection concerns.
        li.textContent = user + ' says ' + message;
    };

    //This does not get called
    reportHubProxy.on("sendMessage", function (user, message)
    {
        console.log(user + ' ' + message);
    });

    $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function ()
        {
            document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
            console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id);
            // Wire up Send button to call NewreportMessage on the server.
            $('#sendButton').click(function ()
            {
                var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
                var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
                console.log(user + ' ' + message + ' sent - connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id);
                reportHubProxy.server.sendMessage(user, message)
                    .then(function (err)
                    {
                        return console.log(user + ' ' + message + ' complete - connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err)
                    {
                        return console.error(err.toString());
                    });
                //$('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        })
        .fail(function ()
        {
            console.log('Could not Connect!');
        });
});
```

I'd tried using a generated proxy before but hadn't noticed the important note that:

> As you can see from the examples, when you use the generated proxy,
> $.connection.hub refers to the connection object. This is the same
> object that you get by calling $.hubConnection() when you aren't using
> the generated proxy.

Note also that, when creating the hub proxy, you use $.connection.reportHub (without the .hub).

I still can't get the client-side 'on' event to trigger - so, let me know if you know how to fix that.

I changed my server hub to:

```
mports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class ReportHub
    Inherits Hub

    Public Sub SendMessage(ByVal user As String, ByVal message As String)
        Clients.All.receiveMessage(user, message)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now I just need to work out how to integrate this into my project, set up token handling etc.